# Meteor - phantomjs rendering of public assets

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

I am working on a Meteor project where I need to generate a PDF export of a section from the page.
I use webshot to generate the export.
A recent requirement is to use a public static asset - a logo image - in the export.
I worked around making css assets available to phantomjs by reading all the css files and copying their content into style tags in the HTML doc I let webshot consume. That works fine.
For the images, I replace the "./images/" pattern in the HTML with the full path to the images folder on the server using

```
const buildPath = path.resolve('.').split(path.sep + 'server')[0];
const imagePath = buildPath + '/web.browser/app/images/';
```

which runs on the server. The image doesn't show up. 
When I open the generated HTML (I save it for debugging) at any place on my dev machine, the image path is resolved fine, and I get the image.

What is the right way to access those static assets in phantomjs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! PhantomJS works as any browser does, but it has some bugs. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Did you give enough time for the image to load? Could you show a minimal working example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out - I was missing a fully qualified protocol in the src attribute of the img tag. While Chrome is smart and forgiving, phantomjs is not.
So basically I had to add 'file:///' before the full path to the image.
It now looks like:

```
const buildPath = path.resolve('.').split(path.sep + 'server')[0].replace(/\\/g, '/');
const imagePath = buildPath + '/web.browser/app/images/';
html = html.replace(/src="\.\/images\//g, 'src="file:///' + imagePath);
```

And as for the comment regarding time, I do give full 1 sec delay for rendering, but didn't check if it works without it.